# Unity3d iPhone SQLite database is empty when launch the app in iOS Device

Tags: c#, ios, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I am creating database connection in my Unity3d game and i am deploying it on iOS device. Database connection is working fine but my database is empty though i have pre-fill it before launch.

I am using Unity 4.0.1 Pro and my xCode 4.6 and code in C# language.

Here is my code in c#

```
void Start ()
    {

        string connectionString;    


        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer) {



            connectionString = "URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/Database.db";

        } else {

            connectionString = "URI=file:Database.db";          

        }

        Debug.Log ("Connection String = " + connectionString);

        IDbConnection dbcon;
        dbcon = (IDbConnection)new SqliteConnection (connectionString);
        dbcon.Open ();

        Debug.Log ("Start DB");

        IDbCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand ();

        string sql =
          "SELECT * from Test ";
        dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
        IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader ();

        while (reader.Read()) {
            Debug.Log ("IN WHILE");
            string FirstName = reader.GetString (0);

            // Print to Console
            Debug.Log (FirstName);
        }
        // clean up                                                                                                                                 
        reader.Close ();
        reader = null;
        dbcmd.Dispose ();
        dbcmd = null;
        dbcon.Close ();
        dbcon = null;

    }
```

and i am getting following error in console.

```
SqliteException: SQLite error
no such table: Test
  at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLite3.Prepare (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection cnn, System.String strSql, Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, System.String& strRemain) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.BuildNextCommand () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Please help me.

Comment: Did you create any table in that database?

Comment: @NicolasDai Yes i have crested table in database.

Comment: @NicolasDai I found the problem . My database is stored under the unity3d.app package and i am accesing the Document Folder. Now how can i access unity3d.app/myDatabase.db?

Comment: I got your problem now, and there is another way to fix it, and I modified my answer, you can try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have solved the problem.

Actually when i m run the app in iPhone then my pre-fill database is stored to unit3d.app package and i am accessing the Document folder. So it is creating a new database to Document folder so that my database was empty.

Now how to connect that pre-fill database :

i have create one function which will return the path till the unity3d.app  and the function is here :

```
public static string GetiPhoneDocumentsPath ()
    { 

        string path = Application.dataPath.Substring (0, Application.dataPath.Length - 5); 
        return path; 
    }
```

Now the final code for connecting to the database :

string connectionString;

```
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer) {


        connectionString = "URI=file:" + GetiPhoneDocumentsPath() + "/SqliteTestDB.db";


    } else {

        connectionString = "URI=file:SqliteTestDB.db";          

    }

    Debug.Log ("Connection String = " + connectionString);

    IDbConnection dbcon;
    dbcon = (IDbConnection)new SqliteConnection (connectionString);
    dbcon.Open ();
```

If anybody have issue for connection database then they can contact me.

Thanks 
Yashesh.

Comment: Why are you trimming 5 chars off the datapath?  This isn't clear.

Comment: Because data path contain "/Data" which need to be removed from path.

Comment: Your solution did not work for me, as my db file could not be located there.  I'm actually not sure why your solution would work; my comment above was more to understand the rational behind the change to the path.  I did find a clear solution here which works for me:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822502/applicationdata-persistentdatapath-unity-editor-to-android/26825890#26825890

Answer (score 0):

The connection string is different between android and IOS, before you query your data base, you need to do this:

```
connectionString= "Data Source=" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/Database.db";

switch (Application.platform)
{
    case RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer:
         datasource = "Data Source=" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/Database.db";
         break;
    case RuntimePlatform.Android:
         datasource = "URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/Database.db";
         break;
}
```

In IOS the connection string should be like this "Data Source=xxxxxxxx", so you can try this.